# 'Where' clause for searching a section of a GUID?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a set of entities with a GUID property, and I want to be able to filter these entities based on a substring of that property. For example, this would be ideal:

```
from e in entities where e.Id.ToString().Contains(searchTerm) select e
```

However, Entity Framework does not accept this as the ToString() method does not exist.

The `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` function does not have a GUID overload.

If there is a way to convert a `DbQuery<T>` to an `ObjectQuery<T>` in Entity Framework 5 then I think I could do the following:

```
objQuery.Where("Id like '%@searchTerm%'", new ObjectParameter("searchTerm", searchTerm))
```

However I can't figure out a way to convert the existing query object.

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Sounds like you're using a guid for something guids aren't designed to do.  You're probably better off refactoring your database to use something other than a GUID if you want to do something other than uniquely identify the item.

Comment: We also need to see what your data looks like; can you give us a few sample columns? Also, the *why* of you are using GUIDs that way will be helpful, so we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: Sadly that's not an option - the guid is a Microsoft Dynamics ID reference to another database. I realise that this isn't the typical use case but my customers want to be able to search for a portion of a GUID. If it's impossible then I'll tell them that but if it's possible I'd rather supply that functionality.

Comment: You could always create a stored proc or DB function that does the operation you want, so that the EF query need only call that.

Comment: @AlexG Why would part of the GUID be useful (information we need)? Moreover, why would multiple sequential GUIDs with the same middle four characters be useful?

Comment: What if you do something really dumb and wasteful like create a computed column which converts the GUID to a varchar(32) and query the computed column. If you're searching frequently, then `PERSISTED` will be of assistance.

Comment: @billinkc - It is not necessary for this to be `PERSISTED` to be indexed. I'd save the 36 bytes per row and do it at runtime as a non persisted computed column. I doubt the CPU cost of converting will outweigh the IO cost of bloating the row. If the table is very wide indexing the computed column might help though, which will materialize it, though the utility of an index on this is dubious anyway as leading wildcard.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker it's for convenience in narrowing down a bunch of records.

billinkc that sounds like an interesting approach, I'll look into it. Thanks